# SQL Loader INFILE from server

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have a SQL*Loader Control File on my computer.

The input data file on the server is `C:\data\myfile.csv`.
In ctl file I add `INFILE 'C:\data\myfile.csv'`.

I have run with command:

```
sqlldr admin/admin@//192.10.1.1:1521/orcl control=myctlfile.ctl
```

The log file:

> SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Tue Sep 18 16:09:00
>    2018 Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
>   All rights reserved.
>   SQL*Loader-500: Unable to open file (C:\data\myfile.csv)
>   SQL*Loader-553: file not found
>   SQL*Loader-509: System error: The system cannot find the file specified.

When I move file `C:\data\myfile.csv` from server to my computer it works fine.

I want to use a file on the server. Is this feasibile?

Comment: SQL\*Loader is a client application. If it can't see the file, it can't load it.

Comment: thanks @WilliamRobertson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL*Loader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-sql-loader.html) is a client application. It needs to be able to open the file, otherwise it can't load it.

If the file is on a remote server, you might look at network folder sharing ([Windows public folder sharing, SkyDrive](https://www.lifewire.com/network-file-sharing-in-microsoft-windows-818219), [Samba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_(software)) etc) to make the remote file accessible from your desktop.